# What would be the helm function to get value from a complex map?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

We have several values that are AWS region dependent. So I have this in my `values.yaml` file

```yaml
regional_values:
  us-east-1:
    repository: 01234567890.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    serviceSecurityGroup1:
    - sg-01234567
    - sg-12345678
    - sg-23456789
    ...
  us-west-1:
    repository: 98765432109.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    serviceSecurityGroup1:
    - sg-34567890
    - sg-45678901
    - sg-56789012
    ...
```

When I do a `helm install` I pass the `aws_region`

```
$ helm install myApp myChart/ --set aws_region
```

What would be a helper function to return say `.Values.regional_values.us-east-1.repository`, so I get `01234567890.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`?

```golang
{{/*
Get the repository from the AWS region
*/}}
{{- define "microservice-base-chart.reponame" -}}
{{/* I know this syntax is wrong */}}
{{- get .Values.regional_values .Values.aws_region.repository }}
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked, but what's a better way? Is there a way to streamline the `$idx :=` and the `printf` lines into one?

```yaml
{{/*
Get the repository from the AWS region
*/}}
{{- define "microservice-base-chart.reponame" -}}
{{- $idx := index .Values.regional_values .Values.aws_region }}
{{- printf "%s" $idx.repository }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: You could just output `$idx.repository` in the last line; or combine the two lines into one expression `(index ...).repository`; or include `"repository" as an additional argument to `index`.